# Why do access modifiers affect list initialization?

Tags: c++

Why do access modifiers affect constructor matching during list initialization?

```
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    int a;
    std::string s;
    float f;
};

class Bar {
    int a;
    std::string s;
    float f;
};

int main() {
    Foo obj{0, "", 0.0f};
    // Bar obj2{0, "", 0.0f};    // Error! 

    return 0;
}
```

If you uncomment it, you will get a compilation error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:18:25: error: no matching function for call to 'Bar::Bar(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
    18 | Bar obj2{0, "", 0.0f};
       | ^
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'Bar::Bar()'
    10 | class Bar {
       | ^~~
<source>:10:7: note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'Bar::Bar(const Bar&)'
<source>:10:7: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'Bar::Bar(Bar&&)'
<source>:10:7: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

Is there a way to achieve direct list-initialization of a simple class (just an aggregation of private variables)?

Or is there a way to have the compiler automatically generate a constructor for me that functions similarly?

Comment: What you are refering to is "aggregate initialization" which has its own set of rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Think of it this way: declaring a member as private, you are *hiding* it as an implementation detail. Why would you want it to be directly initialized by someone else?

Comment: As a side-note: A class with all members `public` is almost the same as a `struct` (inheritance differ, but otherwise they are the same).

Comment: Aggregate initialization only applies to *aggregates*. Your second class is NOT an aggregate, due to private members. Search online for "when is a class an aggregate".

Comment: How do you make members have a private access modifier but also need a direct initialization?!!!

Comment: @BassamNajeeb You can't. But you can make it *look* like direct initialization by adding a (public) constructor that takes the relevant arguments.

Comment: Sure @AdrianMole
He need a public ctr or make it struct